# .Net Core 2.1 templates missing from VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I have VS2017 (15.5.4) Professional already installed and today I installed .Net Core SDK 2.1.4 but I cannot see any Core templates in the New Project dialog in VS.

If I run dotnet --version in Powershell, it correctly shows me 2.1.4 installed

I have removed all Core installations on my windows 10 machine, reinstalled 2.1.4, run the repair on VS and also tried devenv /installvstemplates but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any templates: Make sure VS has the necessary components, make sure that the cross platform development workload is installed through the Visual Studio Installer.

The SDK 2.1.* only contains the 2.0.* runtimes. At the time of writing, there has been no public preview release for .NET Core 2.1.

You can download 2.2.0 SDK previews from https://github.com/dotnet/cli.

Note that the naming may change in the near future in order to avoid confusion and keep the SDK and Runtime major and minor versions in sync - see https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/29.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how your answer says that the templates are not installed by SDK 2.1, even if they are older 2.0 templates, shouldn't there be something there?

Comment: Any templates (e.g. 2.0) or .NET Core 2.1 templates? maybe I got your question wrong.

Comment: There aren't any Core templates listed. I think the VS repair has now also deleted all the templates from my user folder, so I might need to go crazy, remove, clean and reinstall.

Comment: see first part of my answer - is the cross platform workload installed?

Comment: I'm sure it was all related but eventually removed all 3 years of VS installations, reinstalled 2017 and update 4 and everything seems to be back!

Comment: Nice, Microsoft messed up the version numbers a bit... Thanks this solved my issue.

Answer (score 9):

For .NET Core 2.1, you need **Visual Studio version 15.7** or higher.  (check it from Help menu > About Microsoft Visual Studio). So, first ensure you have update your visual studio.

Now, to add .NET Core 2.1 (or other newer templates) to visual studio, you need to install the [**Latest .Net Core SDK** from here](https://github.com/dotnet/core#download-the-latest-net-core-sdk).

Comment: Very helpful for me. I downloaded the .NET Core SDK from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks

Comment: Thank you for this. Amazing that I can read roughly 1,200 MSDN posts and none of them seemed to indicate with such simplicity that all I needed to do was to update my IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Update Visual Studio to version 15.6.0.

Comment: @Robert Columbia Very Thankful.