# .NET core 2.1 template missing

Tags: .net

I have VS2017 Enterprise edition with version 15.7.1 and .Net Core SDK 2.1.4 installed in my machine. However .Net core 2.1 template is missing. m I missing some components to be installed? Any thoughts!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net Core 2.1 templates missing from VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384288/net-core-2-1-templates-missing-from-vs2017)

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading it manually, through Visual Studio's "Extensions and Updates":

- Select the "Tools" tab and click on "Extensions and Updates"
  [image]
- On the new window, at the left side, click on "Online"
  [image]
- On the top right there's a "Search" box, type "ASP.NET Core Template Pack" and Download the first option
  [image]

Thats it, you should now have the templates. If having any trouble, try using this link to download the pack:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack20173